# Class does not conform to 'CBPeripheralManagerDelegate' in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, cbperipheral

I'm trying to build iBeacon emitter in Swift and I cannot get my class to adopt the `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` protocol.

This protocol is required in Objective-C for initializing the PeripheralManager object, but in Swift, I will get the following error:

```
class MyBeacon: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    // ...
}
```

gives error:

> 'MyBeacon' does not conform to 'CBPeripheralManagerDelegate'

Since my class is not adopting the protocol, I also get an error when I try to initialize the PeripheralManager using auto complete

```
self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: queue)
```

gives error:

> Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Can anyone please shed some light?

Comment: Did you implement the methods of the protocol?

Comment: I forgot to put in the peripheralManagerDidUpdateState function. It's all good now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to implement this method as this method not optional and must be implemented if you confirming `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate`

```
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {

}
```

write this in class error will go off

refer [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

> The delegate of a CBPeripheralManager object must adopt the
>   CBPeripheralManagerDelegate protocol, a protocol consisting of
>   numerous optional methods and **one required method**.The protocol’s
>   required method, which indicates whether the peripheral manager is
>   available, is called when the peripheral manager’s state is updated.

Comment: oh man I missed that part... I even had it in the Objective C version... Thanks!!!!!!!!!