# Objective-C warning: Class 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'CBPeripheralManagerDelegate'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm trying to create an Obj-C, CoreBluetooth virtual peripheral app and get this warning.

```
//
//  ViewController.h
//  sim_backend_empty3
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <CBPeripheralManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CBPeripheralManager *peripheralManager;

@end


//
//  ViewController.m
//  sim_backend_empty3
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController   >>>>>>>>>> WARNING >>>>>>>>>>   Class 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'CBPeripheralManagerDelegate'

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)start_BLE_advertisements
{
    [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];
    
}


@end
```

Comment: as soon you read `delegate` in a code and set it `self` you need to implement its methods in the very same class. **cmd-click** on `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate`-> jump to definition and read. go back to your class impl. set cursor in between @impl and @end and type i.e. `-pe` watch what happens.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class does not conform to 'CBPeripheralManagerDelegate' in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872187/class-does-not-conform-to-cbperipheralmanagerdelegate-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the required `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` protocol method:

[peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanagerdelegate/1393271-peripheralmanagerdidupdatestate?language=objc)

as mentioned in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanagerdelegate?language=objc

> The protocol’s required one method, peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:, which Core Bluetooth calls whenever the peripheral manager’s state updates to indicate whether the peripheral manager is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out an Objective-C example of how to setup CoreBluetooth using this repo:

https://github.com/LGBluetooth/LGBluetooth

Back when I still coded in ObjC, it was the library I used - and it was pretty great.

At the very least, it will give you some ideas on how you should be implementing the interfaces.

Here is a Swift implementation of what it sounds like you're trying to do (based on your other question asked a few days ago). Maybe you can backport it to ObjC (disclaimer: I'm the author).

https://github.com/RobotPajamas/SwiftyTeeth/blob/master/Sources/SwiftyTooth/SwiftyTooth.swift